# OnClick Hide Div with Pure JavaScript for Notification bar

Tags: javascript

I am creating a notification bar with a close button. I am using the below code.

```js
document.getElementById("close").onclick = function() {
  var d = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    d[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar">
  <p>
    Dummy Text  <a class="button light" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener opener noreferrer">Get Now</a><button id="close" href="#">X</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

The code is working fine, it closes the div but the problem is my whole site gets blank after clicking the close button.

Comment: Because you are hiding all `div` most like. Use `document.getElementById("top-bar")`  instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`. Note that `getElementById()` returns a single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting all the "div" elements here:

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

Change it for something like:

```
var d = document.getElementById("top-bar");
```

With getElementById, you now will be getting just one element, so the "for" is not required:

```
document.getElementById("close").onclick = function() {
  var d = document.getElementById("top-bar");
  d.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: also he needs to drop the `for` since it's now a single element and not a list

Comment: Is there any way to remove a class after onclick event in this code?

Comment: @SurajKatwal someElement.classList.remove('className')

Comment: @Symphonic The above code is working fine but when I click the close button everything disappears but there appears some background from a class so I wanted to remove that class name so I added `element.classList.remove("className");` just below `var d = document.getElementById("top-bar");` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add type="button" to your "button" tag and remove href attribute as this is not an "a" tag.